# Как правильно смержить 2 ветки разных репозиториев

Tags: git

Есть 2 репозитория. Один с файлами, а другой новый (только создал)
и я хочу затянуть все файлы из первого репозитория во второй из ветки v61Development в Development нового репозитория
сделано `git remote add -f Development C:\Dev\Git\Project`

[image: https://prnt.sc/1xx7r8h]

мне нужно v61Development скопировать в новый репозиторий в ветку Development

а вот дальше не пойму что сделать. помогите пож

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Склонировать репо 1 в папку А, сделать там git reset --hard на нужную ветку, в проводнике скопировать файлы из папки А в папку Б (репо 2). Сделать коммит в репо 2.

Answer (score 0):

В новом репозитории выполняете команду:

```
git checkout -b Development Development/v61Development
```

Это создает новую ветку от последнего комита в ветке `v61Development`.

Comment: `Это создает новую ветку от последнего комита` — плохая, как мне представляется, формулировка. она вполне подошла бы, например, для svn, где ветка — это **набор** коммитов, но для git, где ветка — это всего лишь указатель на коммит, такая формулировка, по-моему, несколько сбивает с толку.